# How to dynamically change status bar icon color for edge to edge?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

When trying to develop your app to make it "edge to edge" and have your app content flow through the system bars, how do you deal with incompatible background colors and system icon colors?

[In this guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge), it says you can set the icon colors to make it suit light background colors (transparent).

```
  <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">
    true
  </item>
```

However, this isn't dynamic. It will make the icon colors black/grey-ish.

Let's say your app's content can be top half white, bottom half black. Your system icons will be visible on the white half but as you scroll down to the black half, now your icons are barely visible with dark front on dark background.

Is there some way for the system to just dynamically adjust its system font colors to match the background showing underneath it?